# Saving multiple values in an array using openCV

Tags: python, arrays, image, numpy, opencv

I am trying to save the x,y positions of the centroids of a series of images using OpenCV.

My code is:

```
import cv2 as cv
import glob
import numpy as np
import os

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# Read the Path

path1 = r"D:\Direction of folder" 

for file in os.listdir(path1): # imagens from the path 
    if file.endswith((".png",".jpg")): # Images formats 

        # Reed all the images 

        Image = cv.imread(file)

        # RGB to Gray Scale
        
        GS = cv.cvtColor(Image, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        th, Gray = cv.threshold(GS, 128, 192, cv.THRESH_OTSU)
        
        # Gray Scale to Bin

        ret,Binari = cv.threshold(GS, 127,255, cv.THRESH_BINARY)

        # Moments of binary images

        M = cv.moments(Binari)

        # calculate x,y coordinate of center

        cX = [int(M["m10"] / M["m00"])]
        cY = [int(M["m01"] / M["m00"])]

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

How can I store all x,y positions of the variables cX and cY in an array?

Comment: Create an empty list. Append `cX` and `cY` for each object as a tuple `(cX, cY)` to the list. Finally, convert the list to an array using numpy: `array = np.asarray(list)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create two empty lists before the `for` loop as follows:

```
cXs, cYs = [], []
for file in os.listdir(path1):
```

Append the values after the `cX` and `cY` lines as follows:

```
    cX = [int(M["m10"] / M["m00"])]
    cY = [int(M["m01"] / M["m00"])]
    cXs.append(cX)
    cYs.append(cY)
```

You can use them after the end of the `for` loop. For example:

```
print(cXs)
print(cYs)
```

You can convert them to `numpy` arrays, if required, as follows:

```
cXs = np.array(cXs)
cYs = np.array(cYs)
```